# Component accept touch events but ignore pan?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

So I have a `FlatList` with a `View` absolute-positioned on top of it.

I'm trying to set it up so `Pressable`s inside the `View` can accept touch events, but ignores pan events (thus, the pan event is consumed by the `FlatList`, i.e, you can tap buttons in the view, but panning on the view pans the `FlatList` itself.

```
            <View style={styles.listContainer}>
{ /* Pan events on the view below actually pan this FlatList */ }
                <FlatList
                    data={collection.items}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    snapToInterval={300}
                    snapToAlignment={'start'}
                    decelerationRate={'fast'}
                    contentContainerStyle={{
                        paddingTop: SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.15,
                        paddingBottom: SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.35
                    }}
                    ref={flatListRef}
                    viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs={viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs.current}
                    {...panResponder.panHandlers}
                />
{ /* This view can be tapped, but not panned */ }
                <View
                    style={styles.collectionItemContentContainer}
                    {...panResponder.panHandlers}
                >
                    <CollectionItemContent
                        item={collection.items[visibleIndex]}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
```

I've tried getting the `dy` from the View's PanResponder and setting `scrollToOffset` on the FlatList, but this ignores all velocity and simply scrolls it to that position (as expected).

`pointerEvents: 'none' or 'box-none'` allow the panning, but then `Pressable` doesn't respond.

I've also tried setting `pointerEvents: none` on the View when a pan starts, but this only works after releasing the pan and starting again.

Is such a thing possible?